# Problem installing Pattern Lab 3 plus Twig

Tags: twig, patternlab.io

I'm having some trouble with Pattern Lab 3 plus Twig.

Following the instructions at `https://patternlab.io/docs/installation.html`:

1. I install with: `npm create pattern-lab`.
2. I choose `Twig (PHP)` as the templating language.
3. I choose `Twig (PHP) demo patterns (full demo website and patterns)` as the the initial patterns

I do see the note `The PHP version of Pattern Lab is being deprecated in favor of a new unified Pattern Lab core. The PHP docs for this topic can be viewed here.`.  Clicking on the link just takes me to installtion page for PHP edition of PL v.2.  Not helpful. So I press on to `https://patternlab.io/docs/generating-pattern-lab.html`.

Next I'm supposed to run `php core/console --watch`.  There is no core sub-directory.  Things are not looking promising.

I remove my PL installation and try again with handlebars templating. With one exception, all is good. The exception: I wanted twig templates.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the PatternLab website you saw around the time you posted this still reflected the 2.x/3.x days. Work is being done to get the legacy out and the current state in.

Last month, I contributed to this package: [`@pattern-lab/engine-twig`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pattern-lab/engine-twig). This engine is a pure Javascript based twig engine which prevents the need for PHP. It uses the [Twing library](https://nightlycommit.github.io/twing/) under the hood (since v5.8.0). There are still things to iron out, but I welcome you to try it. Please file bugs here:

https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternlab-node/issues

Comment: Things have definitely improved since I posted my question. I have gotten it work.